# Choose partition of a set with Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

Suppose I have a set represented by an array of strings, like

> set = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" }

I would like to create a Manipulate which allows the user to build repartitions of the set. To be clear, I'd like the user to be able to build, for instance, the following repartitions:

```
repa1 = { {"A", "B", "C"}, {"D", "E", "F"} }
```

and

```
repa2 = { { "A" }, { "B", "C" }, { "D", "E", "F" } }
```

$$ $$
Is this possible?

---

Even better, I would like to be able to use labels for the manipulate command. I mean, let's say the set is

> set = { {"A", 26}, {"B", 33}, {"C", 69}, {"D", 2}, {"E", 16} }

then the selector should look like

part1 : [ A, B, C, D, E ]

part2 : [ A, B, C, D, E ]

part3 : [ A, B, C, D, E ]

and, supposing I choose the following combination,

part1 : [ **A**, B, **C**, D, E ]

part2 : [ A, **B**, C, **D**, E ]

part3 : [ A, B, C, D, **E** ]

the result should be

> repa = { { {"A", 26}, {"C", 69} }, {{"B", 33}, {"D", 2}}, {{"E", 16}} }

Comment: Starting point: `Manipulate[part, {{part, {}, part}, {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}, 
  ControlType -> ListPicker}]` ?

Comment: Thanks! A better starting point is : Manipulate[part, {{part, {}, part}, {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}, ControlType -> TogglerBar}]

Comment: Implementation is minor problem. Details matter. Is an order important? How many partitions user can make, only 3 or `n = Length@set`? etc.

Comment: A variable number of partitions would be great, but even a fixed number is ok.
Order doesn't matter, and it would be nice to force the intersection of different parts to be empty

Answer (score 2):

```
DynamicModule[{reset, next, l, new, parts, ok, x},

 Dynamic[      
  Deploy@Grid[{{
      Button["Next part", next[], Enabled -> Dynamic@ok],
      Dynamic[TogglerBar[Dynamic@x, new, Enabled -> ok], TrackedSymbols :> {new}]
      }, {
      Button["Reset", reset[]],
      Dynamic@parts
      }}, BaseStyle -> {Bold, 18}]
  , None]

 , Initialization :> (
   l = CharacterRange["A", "F"];
   reset[] := (new = l; parts = {}; ok = True;);

   next[] := (parts = Join[parts, {x}]; new = Complement[new, x]; x = {}; 
              If[Length@new == 0, ok = False; new = l;]);

   reset[]
   )
 ]
```

> [image]

Comment: This is not "minimal working answer" but I wanted to do this well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can I use this within a manipulate?

Comment: @Abramo you can strip `DynamicModule` and use `Manipulate` but I strongly encourage to avoid `Manipulate` for more complicated projects. Try to create the rest of the program inside `DynamicModule`.

Comment: Ok, I never tried to work with dynamic modules, but I guess this is a good occasion to start! ;-)